# Passport for adopted American w/o birth certificate

Tags: oregon, passport

I was born on a now closed military base in Germany and am an American citizen living in Oregon. I've had two passports in my life, both of which have been lost for quite some time. I have no idea where my original birth certificate is. To complicate matters, my mother and father divorced when I was young, and I was adopted by my mother's second husband, changing my last name.

I can't get an Oregon driver's license without a birth certificate or passport as proof of identification. I'd like to get both my Oregon driver's license and a passport. What are my options?

Comment: Are you 18 or older? Do you have any forms of photo ID? Have you looked at https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/abroad/events-and-records/birth/replace-or-amend-consular-report-of-birth-abroad.html to get a replacement CRBA?

Comment: I am, and I haven't. That looks like exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need replacement documentation (in lieu of a traditional birth certificate), which would be a Consular Report of Birth Abroad (CRBA) for those born outside the US on military bases and other such entities. At `travel.state.gov` see [Replace or Amend a Consular Report of Birth Abroad (CRBA)](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/abroad/events-and-records/birth/replace-or-amend-consular-report-of-birth-abroad.html)

If you don't have sufficient forms of ID to apply, at `travel.state.gov` see [Passport Vital Records IDs](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/abroad/events-and-records/birth/replace-or-amend-consular-report-of-birth-abroad/passport-vital-records-ids.html)

Comment: Glad that helped.